# What part of speech is "there"?

Tags: grammar

"Please, put the books over there"
"Do circuits run back there?"
"Let's get away from there"
"Sam sold his computer to my friend from there"
I am confuse on classify the word "there". Sometimes it sounds like an adverb, sometimes it seems to be a pronoun. How can i distinguish?
The problem is: I think "there" replaces a noun phrase. For exemple, in the 4th sentence. I could replace "there" by "Londres". Is it a pronoun?
In the 1st and 2nd sentences... Are "back" and "over" adverbs or prepositions?

Comment: No, not a pronoun. Traditional grammar and most dictionaries treat locative "there" as an adverb, while some modern grammars treat is as locative preposition. As a preposition of spatial location, it typically means to/in/from some place. In examples like your "Let's get away from there" (where "there" is anaphoric), the "from" component is overtly expressed.

Comment: https://www.learngrammar.net/a/examples-of-adverb-of-place; According to this, 'there' is an adverb of place.

Comment: You're not going to find a consensus on this. It depends on who you ask. Merriam-Webster, for instance, counts it as an adverb in the first two sentences, but as a pronoun in the third sentence. (And not everybody agrees with those differing designations, as previous comments have indicated.) In pragmatic terms, it really doesn't matter what label you use, but only if whatever construction you come up with makes sense.

Comment: Luckily, you don't need a consensus on this. The part of speech that a given word belongs to depends on what set of POS you're using. Words with specific grammatical functions (like _wh_-words, demonstratives, articles, complementizers, and quantifiers in English) don't fit well into the medieval list invented by the Romans to describe Latin.  What's important in English grammar is the constructions that an individual word can occur in, and what structural roles it can assume in an utterance. For this sense of _there_, 'distal deictic demonstrative locative' will probly do as well as anything.

Comment: @JohnLawler Nice to see them being taken out of various dustbins.